# How to get week start date from time stamp in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a data source with a bunch of time stamps. I want to find the week start (sunday) date from these time stamps.

Eg, I want to go from "2022-11-23 00:00:00.0"  --> "2022-11-20" for every date in the column called "Received Date"

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN sorttype = 'sortable' THEN 'Sort'
        WHEN sorttype = 'SORTABLE' THEN 'Sort'
        ELSE 'Non Sort'
    END AS "Sort Type",
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, -1, (order_day + podays_received)), -1) AS "Week Start",
    (order_day + podays_received) AS "Received Date",
    pg_rollup AS "Product Family",
    gl,
    quantity_unpacked AS "Quantity Received"
FROM 
    sba.sba_req_po_received
WHERE
    source = 'OPPORTUNITYBUYING'
    AND country_code = 'US'
    AND NOT buy_type_name = 'Offcycle'
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DATE_TRUNC function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) can return the start of a week. However, it treats **Monday** as the start of the week.

If you want to get Sunday as the start of the week, add a day, then truncate, then subtract a day:

```
select (date_trunc('week', timestamp_field + interval '1 day') - interval '1 day')::date
```

Confused? Here's an example:

- `2022-12-23` is a Tuesday
- Add one day: `2022-11-24` (Wednesday)
- Truncate the 'week': `2022-11-21` (Monday)
- Subtract a day: `2022-11-20` (Sunday)

Now let's try it with a Sunday:

- `2022-12-04` is a Sunday
- Add one day: `2022-12-05` (Monday)
- Truncate the 'week': `2022-12-05` (Same Monday)
- Subtract a day: `2022-12-04` (Sunday)

Answer (score -1):

try this : `select now() - cast(extract('DoW' from now()) || ' day' as interval)`

Comment: Please consider adding more information about what the syntax does so that not only the OP but also the readers get to know things.